# Auto generate row with Twitter Bootstrap in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning, I have found myself in a bit of a dilemma! I am creating a Wordpress theme using Twitter Bootstrap and I am generating the members for the "Meet the Team" page via Wordpress "Posts" I can only fit 3 entries in 1 row... I.E

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

But anymore than 3 entries per a row will break the row, so I need to generate a new row for every 3 entries. How can I do this?

Here is my PHP code for outputting the entries.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=members&orderby=date'); ?>
<div class="row-fluid">
   <ul class="thumbnails">
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <li class="span4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
          <?php // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.the_post_thumbnail();
          ?>
              <div class="pad">
                 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                 <?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
          </div>
       </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=members&orderby=date'); ?>
<div class="row-fluid">
   <ul class="thumbnails">
      <?php 
      $cnt =0;
      if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        if($cnt%3==0){
          echo "</ul></div><div class='row-fluid'><ul clsas='thumbnails'>";
        }

      ?>
      <li class="span4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
          <?php // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.the_post_thumbnail();
          ?>
              <div class="pad">
                 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                 <?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
          </div>
       </li>
    <?php 
    $cnt++;
    endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```